# Closed Immersion between Smooth Schemes is Open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about an argument in the proof of Proposition 6.2.10 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (page 223):

[image]

Following the proof the problem was already reduced to the case that $f: X \to Y$ is a closed immersion.

A previous result (cor. 2.6) impies that $X$ and $Y$ are smooth over $S$ and have same relative dimension in a neighborhood of $X$ (so the dimension of the fibers coinside locally around $x \in X \subset Y$) with respect the smooth maps $X,Y \to S$.

Why does this alreadt imply that $f:X \to Y$ is an ***open immersion***?

Comment: Hint: A flat closed immersion must be an open immersion

Comment: @SamirCanning: So it suffice to show that $f:X \to Y$ is flat. But at one point I encounter following problem:

I intend to use following argument that says if $k: A \to B, j:B \to C$ are morphisms between schemes such that $j$ is ***separated*** and the composition $j \circ k$ has some property $P$ then $k$ has also property $P$. 

In our story $X,Y \to S$ are smooth and therefore ***flat*** := property $P$. Futhermore $X \to S= X \xrightarrow{\text{f}}  Y \to S$ So in order to apply the argument above we need that the smooth $Y \to S$ is separated but I don't see why it holds?

Comment: Or do you have another argument to deduce flatness of $f$ in mind?

Comment: I would use the fact about the dimension of the fibers

Comment: @SamirCanning: Honestly, I don't know a criterion for flatness based on the information about the dimension of fibers. I only know that flatness ***implies*** that the dimension of fibers in constant. But I'm not sure if there exist a similar statement in "other direction".

Comment: @SamirCanning: hmmm, I'm still puzzling over your hint that says if we havegiven equility on dimension of the fibers imply already flatness. 

If I apply the dimension formula for flat morphisms (namely that $h:W \to Z$ flat then $\dim O_{W, w}= \dim W_z + \dim O_{Z,z}$ with $z=h(w)$) to our flat $X,Y \to S$ then I indeed obtain $\dim O_{X,x}=\dim O_{Y,y}$ for $y=f(x)$. If we can somehow assume that $X$ is reduced then we are also done. But I'm not sure if this it the point you meant.

Comment: Could you give the reference for the statement you mentioned above which allows to conclude flatness if we know something about the fibers. This seems to be a quite interesting criterion.

Comment: I was thinking about this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00R4